# Rails 3 - Update div content with Ajax and jquery (nested resources)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

I've two simple models, Pin and Comment, Comments belongs to Pin:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

and

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pin
```

In the index action of Pin I've basically a list of all the pins + a **div**.
This **div** must show all the comments when user select a pin.

Concept is quite simple, but I can't figure out how to achieved it.
I've found many subjects related, but I always lost myself in the differences with my problem.

Some precise questions:

- How to do this ajax load? (with jquery)
- Do I need to use partials or use index view of comments?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to use a link for the user to select a Pin but you get the idea:

```
#:remote => true allows ajax stuffz.
<%= link_to 'show comments', pin_comments_path(@pin), :remote=> true %>
```

In the comments_controller.rb (i'm using the index action here, but tweak to your needs)

```
def index 
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
  @comments = @pin.comments.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :pin_comments }
  end
end
```

In this case the controller will look to render pin_comments.js.erb, which will interact with your comments div.

```
//pin_comments.js.erb
$("#comments_div").html("<%= j(render('show_comments', :comments=> @comments)) %>");
```

View partial template to show comments

```
#_show_comments.html.erb
<div id="comments_div">
    <% comments.each do |c| %> 
        <p>
           <h1><%= c.title %></h1>
           <h6>by <%= c.author %> </h6>
           <%= c.content %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!