# Ajax to reload div content in Rails 4 error + where to put remote: true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to periodically refresh a div on my screen. 
the div is in my index.html.erb and looks like this

```
<div id="shared_tasks_div">
<ul>
  <% @canEditTasks.each do |elem| %>
     <div class="draggable">    
     some code to put elem values in <p>
     </div>
  <% end %>
    <% @canView.each do |elem| %>
    <div class="draggable">    
     some code to put elem values in <p>
    </div>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

in my task controller I added the following code

```
  def index
    @tasks = current_user.task
    @canEditTask = some query
    @canView = another query
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :div_tasks }
    end
  end
```

I created the following js `div_tasks.js.erb` in my app/views/tasks

```
$("#shared_tasks_div").html("<%= j(render('index', :canEditTasks=> @canEditTasks)) %>");
$("#shared_tasks_div").html("<%= j(render('index', :canView=> @canView)) %>");
```

I now have to issue
a) where should I put the `remote: true`
b) I am getting the following error from my index method

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :div_task }
```

I did see the following two posts and integrated some of the suggestions to my solution, but it did not solve the issue
[Rails 4 ajax update div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843185/rails-4-ajax-update-div)
[Rails 3 - Update div content with Ajax and jquery (nested resources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470953/rails-3-update-div-content-with-ajax-and-jquery-nested-resources)

thank you for your help

Comment: Your `div_notes.js.erb` should be in `app/views/tasks` directory and not in `app/assets/javascripts` directory.  Also your error shows `render :div_task` but your `index` action has `div_notes`.  Is this error after you've tried out the answers from posted links?

Comment: I moved the file, and the div_note was a typo in my post. I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes this is the error after I tried to implement my ajax refresh with the help of the links I posted here

Comment: can it be that the error is a result of not having remote somewhere in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a periodic javascript ajax call to your index.html.erb file. The javascript should include an ajax call (dataType: script will insure that format.js) to the index method in your task controller.

You can use the methods outlined here:
[How to fire AJAX request Periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically)

Comment: Hey I am having a hard time figuring it out. would you be able to give me a more concrete example